# How to specify file name and location with xlsxwriter

Tags: python, excel, xlsxwriter

I am new to python and looking to make a program that looks through a given folder, looks at each workbook and pulls a specific cell, and uses that cell as the name of a new workbook being created.  I can pull the name pretty easily and store it, however I cannot figure out how to use this with the xlsxwriter function to save the new workbook.  Is there any way to specify both the location and file name using xlsxwriter?

```
for files in filenames:
    oldWorkBook = openpyxl.load_workbook(files)
    lotWorkSheet = oldWorkBook['Order Entry']
    newFileName = lotWorkSheet.cell(row = 8, column = 14)

    workbook = xlsxwriter.Workbook(r"C:\Users\sf\Documents\Test Files\")
    worksheet = workbook.add_worksheet('data')
    worksheet.write('A1', 'Hello..')
    workbook.close()
```

The first part works and newFileName is successfully housing the name of the worksheet I want to use.  However, I can't figure out how to successfully name the workbook based on the variable.

Any help is much appreciated!

Comment: Replace `r"C:\Users\sf\Documents\Test Files\"` with `r"C:\Users\sf\Documents\Test Files"`?

Comment: You should be getting a `SyntaxError: EOL while scanning string literal` from the `r"C:\Users\sf\Documents\Test Files\"` because you cannot end a string literal with a backslash. You should be specifying a *filename* — not a directory — when creating a `Workbook` anyway, so use something like `workbook = xlsxwriter.Workbook(r"C:\Users\sf\Documents\Test Files\data.xlsx"`. See the [documentation](https://xlsxwriter.readthedocs.io/workbook.html).